# WCF Message Encryption with in memory x509Certificate2 Certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate2, azure-keyvault

I would like to be able to use a certificate that I have in memory and not from the "Current User" or "Current Machine" certificate store.

Our desire is to have multiple WCF clients (with the same service) that we connect to and store their public key in a database.  Then, by some convention, pick which certificate to encrypt the message with.  I do not want to have this stored in the Web.config nor have it stored in the local machines keystore.  We are needing this to be agnostic of where it is deployed (Azure vs on-prem vs whatever).

I know that this would work:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cert.Thumbprint);
```

But I want to do:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(x509Certificate);
```

Is this possible for an app to have it's own keystore, like in Java?

Answer (score 0):

[`X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificaterecipientclientcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) defines a [`DefaultCertificate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificaterecipientclientcredential.defaultcertificate(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is settable.

According to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Security/X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential.cs,eaccbfb7a59b7226,references the property sets the same backing field as `SetDefaultCertificate`.